# How to display remember me and submit buttons inline using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display remember me checkbox and submit button inline using Bootstrap 3 inside my Login form.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div> 
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

They do not align vertically very well, especially on mobile size. I would like them to be vertically aligned so the `checkbox` is in the middle of `Submit` button.
Also `Remember me` label is not aligned nicely with `checkbox`, it seems like words `Remember me` are slightly higher than `chekcbox`.

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create another `row` class inside of the first one. Then inside of that create two classes of two, so `col-x-6` twice. Inside one place the check box and inside the other place the button. Then use CSS to clean up and misalignment.

I don't know if this will solve the problem, but it may be worth a try!:)